# .NET 4.5.1 broke MSBUILD

Tags: msbuild

We've been using TeamCity for some time without issues.  We went a few weeks without doing builds and our server team installed .NET 4.5.1 on the server.  Now all of our builds are breaking.

Here is the command line being ran (edited for privacy):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>msbuild "C:\programs\TeamCity\bu
ildAgent\work\<path to proj file>.csproj" /t:Package /P:Configuration=Test
```

Which results in this error:

```
The target "Package" does not exist in the project.
```

Lots of results talk about this being a missing visual studio folder named "web" or not having web deploy installed.  That is not the case here.  Those solutions are not working.